# AS3 keep blank lines but remove leading spaces before word after line breaks

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Actual:

```
 A new line begins

     Another line begins
       Here's another
```

Expected:

```
A new line begins

Another line begins
Here's another
```

So far I have tried this which removes all the leading spaces before word after line breaks:

```
var regex:RegExp = /(\r?\n|\r)+(\s+|\s+$)/g;
var newText:String = abcd.replace(regex, "\n");
Alert.show(StringUtil.trim(newText));
```

But I'm having difficulty to set a condition to leave blank lines as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option is to match and remove only the spaces at the start of lines, and never newlines:

```
var regex:RegExp = /^[ \t]+/gm;
var newText:String = abcd.replace(regex, "");
```

- Use the `/m` (multiline) flag, so `^` matches at the beginning of every line.
- Match only spaces and tabs, not line breaks.
- Simply remove them.
- This will also remove spaces from space-only lines. If that's a problem you can use `^[ \t]+(?=\S)`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/gdMZLZ/2

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I want to keep the space-only lines. When I've tried this /^[ \t]+(?!\s)+/gm it also removes the space-only lines (to newText).

Comment: @SantanuKarar - In your comment you have an extra `+`, that could be the cause of an error - in Regex101 it shows: "The preceding token is not quantifiable".

Comment: If you have pointed the + symbol before /gm, I have removed it to /^[ \t]+(?!\s)/gm but still it removes space-only lines.

Comment: @SantanuKarar - I can't find an ActionScript compiler or interpreter online to test it, but it is working in https://regex101.com/r/gdMZLZ/3 .

Comment: @SantanuKarar - Just making sure - you are using `StringUtil.trim` in your test. This will also remove empty lines from the beginning and the end of your string, but not from the middle.

Comment: Oh yes, I have removed the StringUtil.trim before the test suggested by you )

Comment: I noticed I didn't had \n to the blank line I was testing with. Once I added the \n in the blank line, everything starts working expectedly. Thank you!!

Comment: @SantanuKarar - Oh, good point.  I missed that case. This will work also for spaces at the end, if we want to keep them: `^[ \t]+(?=\S)` - It matches spaces at the beginnings of lines that have a non-space character: https://regex101.com/r/gdMZLZ/4

Comment: Thank you @Kobi, for this tuning. Yes, I want to remove only the leading spaces but trailing. (?=\S) should be more prominent in my need.